# Remove object within array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an object and within that object, I have an array of objects. I'm trying to remove a single object from within the array. My code right now removes the entire object and I'm not sure why. Any thoughts?

eg: `Collection example`

```
"profiles": {
  "names": [
    {
      "first": "Joe",
      "last": "First",
      "uniqueId": "075ae7fda11"
    },
    {
      "first": "Sam",
      "last": "Last",
      "uniqueId": "1488096533"
    }
  ]
}
```

eg. `Update method`

```
MyCollection.update({_id: userId}, {
  $unset: {
    profiles: {
      'names.$.first': 'Joe'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: "and I'm not sure why" - it's because you didn't read documentation. It says: "The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation." So it doesn't matter _what_ you pass as a value to `profile` there, the entire subdocument will be removed. That's what `$unset` does.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't that mean it should remove the entire object with `Joe` in it. Not remove the entire `profiles` object??

Comment: No, it removes entires `profiles` because _that_ is what you said to unset.

Comment: Ok. Can you show me it's supposed to look like?

Comment: I think you want `$pull` or `$pullAll` operators

Comment: I added one answer that might help you. let me know if it worked or not. @bp123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull) operator to remove all matching objects.

```
MyCollection.update({_id: userId}, {
  "$pull": {
    "profiles.names": {
      "first": "Joe"
    }
  }
});
```

To remove single object using [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).When you use positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update) operator with update operation the array field must appear as part of the query document [check docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

```
MyCollection.update({_id: userId,"profiles.names.first":"Joe"},{ 
   "$unset":{
      "profiles.names.$":""
   }  
});
```

**Important Note** :  `$unset` replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and element positions.

So the execution of above query will update your names array and it will look like:

```
"profiles": {
  "names": [
    null,
    {
      "first": "Sam",
      "last": "Last",
      "uniqueId": "1488096533"
    }
  ]
}
```

Removing of object completely is not yet supported by monngodb, see the open bug:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it,

```
MyCollection.update({ _id: userId) },
    {
        "$pull":
            {
                "profiles.names":
                    {
                        "first": "Joe"
                    }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$pull removes an element from an array.

$unset removes the whole array (or any other field).